# MongoDB insert_many not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have a text file with data as

`t1:v1
t2:v2
t3:v3
t1:v1`

and so on

I have to read the file and push into mongodb

I am doing this,

```
import glob
import sys
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

def main():

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('Usage: ./prog_name path')
    else:
        client = MongoClient('localhost', 9999)
        db = client['dbtag']
        collection = db['tctags']
        path = sys.argv[1]
        for tcname in glob.glob(path+'*.txt'):
            with open(tcname) as tfile:
                taglist = tfile.read().splitlines()
                d = {}
                for line in taglist:
                    tagsplit = line.split(':')
                    d[tagsplit[0]] = tagsplit[1]

                print(d, "\n\nonefiledone\n\n")
                print(type(d))
            result = collection.insert_many(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but it throws the error on line 25, `insert_many`:

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON,
           bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from 
           collections.MutableMapping
```

EDIT:

Console output,

```
{'t1': 'v1', 't2': 'v2', 't3': 'v3'}

onefiledone


<class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tagPython.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\tagPython.py", line 25, in main
    result = collection.insert_many(d)
  File "C:\Users\cmehar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 752, in insert_many
    blk.ops = [doc for doc in gen()]
  File "C:\Users\cmehar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 752, in <listcomp>
    blk.ops = [doc for doc in gen()]
  File "C:\Users\cmehar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 743, in gen
    common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)
  File "C:\Users\cmehar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\common.py", line 453, in validate_is_document_type
    "collections.MutableMapping" % (option,))
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

Comment: Where does it throw it?

Comment: I meant which line in the code throws it - if you are unsure post the stack, but it should say so plainly.

Comment: line 25, the insert_many line.

Comment: maybe the variable `d` is not properly constructed

Comment: yeah, i thought so but i printed it out along with it's type, it shows <class 'dict'> clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `insert_many()` requires list of documents (dictionaries) but you provided only one dictionary.
You can just use `insert()` instead of `insert_many()` and this should work.
Or you can split these dictionaries to separate documents and use `insert_many()`.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a single document, so you should be using `insert_one` instead.

With `insert_many`, the fields of `d` are iterated over and each field is being inserted as a document (which fails because they're not dicts).